# Spring @Transaction does not rollback on Exception thrown

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-3

I've searched around for this question, there's quite a few of them here on StackOverflow and Google but I can't seem to get anything working for me.

here are my codes
Spring config: (I dont use any pointcut - I think I dont need to?)

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
...
</bean>

<bean id="hibernateSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
 <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
 ...
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernateSessionFactory"/>
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
```

I have a Service class:

```
@Service
public class ServiceImpl implements ServiceInterface 
{
    /**
     * Injected session factory
     */
    @Autowired(required=true)
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Autowired(required=true)
    private Dao myDao;

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Transactional(rollbackFor=Exception.class, propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public void scheduleBlast(BlastParameters blastParameters) throws ServiceException 
    {
        ... do bunch of stuff ..
        myDao.persist(entity)

        if(true)
            throw new ServiceException("random error")
    }

    .. setter methods and other stuff ..
}
```

and a Dao class:

```
public class DaoImpl implements DaoInterface
{
    @Autowired(required=true)
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.MANDATORY)
    public void persist(Entity e) throws DaoException
    {
        try
        {
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().persist(e);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw new DaoException(ex);
        }
    }


    .. setter methods and other stuff ..
}
```

Some unnecessary details are eliminated (eg. missing setter, etc), assume that code works perfectly fine.

My problem with the above is that when I added the throw random exception line, it does not rollback, the object being persisted through the DAO stays in the db.

I am using Spring 3.1 and Hibernate 3.6 (because there was a bug with Hibernate 4.0 on Spring 3.1)

Thoughts?

Thank you

Comment: Try debugging and see where spring ends up when it has hit your breakpoint. The code is all pretty good really, just make sure you have the source linked in to your IDE !

Comment: which mysql engine are you using MyISAM or InnoDB, MyISAM dont support transactions.

Comment: using innoDB. Another weird part that I just figure out: the service class actually has myDao1.persist(o1) then myDao2.persist(o2) having o2 dependent on o1. I found that the o2 objects are rolled back, but not the o1 object.

Comment: I figured out more steps. So my actual Service class is as follow: Service1: { 1. Dao1.persist 2. Service2.doStuff 3. Dao2.persist } - the original problem comes when I throw the exception after Step 3. It also shows up if thrown after Step 2. It doesn't commit if exception thrown before Step 2. The Service2 class is very similar to the Service1 as above, I also tried Propagation.Required and even tried Propagation.NESTED and it still not working. So seems like sometime between step 1 and step 2 it commits the transaction.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found the cause of my problem and why the transaction (seemingly) not managed properly.

Somewhere in my code

```
/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
@Transactional(rollbackFor=Exception.class, propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
public void doWork(Parameters param) throws ServiceException 
{
    ... do bunch of stuff ..
    myDao1.persist(entity)

    -- Some logic here --

    ... do bunch of stuff ..
    myDao2.persist(entity2)

    if(true)
        throw new ServiceException("random error")
}
```

The part where it says "-- Some logic here --", there was some logic done that uses raw SQL and call on execute update:

```
Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(queryText);
query.executeUpdate();
```

And because it's not using Hibernate query, and instead using raw SQL execution, it caused a flush to be called and thus any work done prior to the call will be committed along with 
it.

I re-work the flow of logic to account for this logic to make sure transaction is managed properly. While using raw SQL might be an indication that there's something wrong - it was something necessary to be done due to the things that the service try to accomplish and to improve the performance of the service.

Comment: A flush - whether automatic or explicit - should NOT commit your transaction. A flush only sends your updated/new entities to the database but those should still be in the same transaction and should not be committed until the @Transactional lifecycle has finished.

Answer (score 16):

That is the intended behavior of transaction management.
The default behavior for @Transactional is to rollback only for runtime exceptions.
If you want your stuff to rollback after throwing DaoException then add it to the rollback exception list. Don't forget to also include RuntimeException also.
Try the following on the Dao class
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.Mandatory, rollbackFor={RuntimeException.class, DaoException.class})

Comment: the exception is thrown in the Service class, so catching the exception on Dao class doesn't help (It already finish calling that class).

Comment: Then add the rollback exception list in Service class's @Transactional annotation

Answer (score 1):

Try remove the @Transactional annotation from the DaoImpl class. I suspect what might be happening is that the transaction is being committed when it crosses back over that transaction boundary (DaoImpl). I've had mixed success with this setup. You can try some different transaction approaches to the "inner" transaction.

The other thing you can do is turn on spring transaction logging. It think its category org.springframework.transaction or something. That way you will see exactly what it is doing w.r.t to roll back and commit of transactions...

Comment: Thanks, I tried removing the @Transactional from Dao classes still doesnt work. See my comment on the original post about weird thing going on. Basically I persist 2 different objects, the first one is committed and not rolled back, the 2nd one is rolledback

Comment: Based on the Spring transaction logging, everything seem to be working exactly the way they are supposed to be. They used the same session, started at the beginning, every persist uses the same one and it's rolledback at the end. From the logging it also says "HibernateTransactionManager - Participating in existing transaction" for both persist calls

Answer (score 0):

you don't have one of those JDBC drivers that are in AUTOCOMMIT mode by default, do you?

Comment: Dont think so, I dont have any AUTOCOMMIT config anywhere for sure. in my <bean> for data source I got: <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue when open connections manually in my Spring Repository. After I start using JdbcTemplate error disappeared

I used

```
@Autowired 
private JdbcTemplate jdbc;
```

in my Repository

and then
`jdbc.query(sql, new RowMapper());` or `jdbc.update(sql);` or `jdbc.queryForObject(sql, new RowMapper());` dependent on how many objects you return by your query.

Also I defined RowMapper():

```
public class RowMapper implements RowMapper<YourDTOObject> {
    @Override
    public YourDTOObject mapRow(ResultSet resultSet, int i) throws SQLException {
        YourDTOObject dto = new YourDTOObject();
        dto.setId(resultSet.getInt("id")); // here you can change to your column names
        dto.setName(resultSet.getString("name"));
        dto.setAmount(resultSet.getBigDecimal("amount"));
        return a;
    }
```